# How can I make pandas dataframe column headers all lowercase?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make all column headers in my pandas data frame lower case

### Example

If I have:

```
data =

  country country isocode  year     XRAT          tcgdp
0  Canada             CAN  2001  1.54876   924909.44207
1  Canada             CAN  2002  1.56932   957299.91586
2  Canada             CAN  2003  1.40105  1016902.00180
....
```

I would like to change XRAT to xrat by doing something like:

```
data.headers.lowercase()
```

So that I get:

```
  country country isocode  year     xrat          tcgdp
0  Canada             CAN  2001  1.54876   924909.44207
1  Canada             CAN  2002  1.56932   957299.91586
2  Canada             CAN  2003  1.40105  1016902.00180
3  Canada             CAN  2004  1.30102  1096000.35500
....
```

I will not know the names of each column header ahead of time.

Comment: More easiest `df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()`

Comment: Hello Nasuki, while the original answer was acceptable at the time of the original question, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38931854/7758804) below, is better. Please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Best Regards.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
data.columns = map(str.lower, data.columns)
```

or

```
data.columns = [x.lower() for x in data.columns]
```

example:

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(3), 'B':range(3,0,-1), 'C':list('abc')})
>>> data
   A  B  C
0  0  3  a
1  1  2  b
2  2  1  c
>>> data.columns = map(str.lower, data.columns)
>>> data
   a  b  c
0  0  3  a
1  1  2  b
2  2  1  c
```

Comment: Note that this can lead to duplicate column names when lower(column1) == lower(column2) (e.g., 'a' and 'A'). This can have unintended consequences when referencing columns later. (e.g. data['a'] will return a DataFrame, not a Series, with all columns named 'a'). See this gist for an example: https://gist.github.com/grisaitis/170e82a008480acb4fa3

Comment: `[x.lower() for x in data.columns]` is equivalent to:
`[x.lower() for x in data]`

Comment: While you are at it, it's good to use `[x.lower().strip() for x in df0]`

Comment: @PawelKranzberg Do you have any idea how to lower the column names of `MultiIndex`

Comment: @curious_nustian - Yes, e.g.: `df.index.names = [x.lower().strip() for x in df.index.names]`

Comment: also `map(str.lower, data.columns)` is equivalent to `map(str.lower, data)`

Comment: I am a fan of the `map` method. Another way: `df.rename(columns={_:_.lower().strip() for _ in df.columns})`

Answer (score 180):

You could do it easily with [`str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) for `columns`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
```

Example:

```
In [63]: df
Out[63]: 
  country country isocode  year     XRAT         tcgdp
0  Canada             CAN  2001  1.54876  9.249094e+05
1  Canada             CAN  2002  1.56932  9.572999e+05
2  Canada             CAN  2003  1.40105  1.016902e+06

In [64]: df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

In [65]: df
Out[65]: 
  country country isocode  year     xrat         tcgdp
0  Canada             CAN  2001  1.54876  9.249094e+05
1  Canada             CAN  2002  1.56932  9.572999e+05
2  Canada             CAN  2003  1.40105  1.016902e+06
```

Answer (score 47):

If you want to do the rename using a chained method call, you can use

```py
data.rename(columns=str.lower)
```

If you're not chaining method calls, you can add `inplace=True`

```py
data.rename(columns=str.lower, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
```

is the easiest but will give an error if some headers are numeric

if you have numeric headers then use this:

```
df.columns = [str(x).lower() for x in df.columns]
```

Comment: I guess it's easier to write `df.columns.astype(str).str.lower()` in that case but maybe a bit verbose.

Comment: These two methods have already been mentioned by the answers above. The only noteworthy comment you make is the case of numeric headers which really should be added to the existing generator answer.

Comment: @Daniel My method is better because it will not break if there are numeric columns. I used the first one for simplicity but frankly the first one should be rejected as it is prone to errors. In short, my method can be a standalone answer without referring to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some of the other answers will fail if a column name is made of digits (e.g. "123"). Try these to handle such cases too.

Option 1: Use [df.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

```py
def rename_col(old_name):
    return str(old_name).lower()

df.rename(rename_col)
```

Option 2 (from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726029/how-can-i-make-pandas-dataframe-column-headers-all-lowercase#comment113164004_62601983)):

```py
df.columns.astype(str).str.lower()
```

Answer (score -1):

Another convention based on the official documentation:

`frame.rename(mapper=lambda x:x.lower(), axis='columns', inplace=True)`

> Parameters:
> mapper:
> Dict-like or function transformations to apply to that axis’ values. Use either mapper and axis to specify the axis to target with mapper, or index and columns.

Comment: I'd say using `frame.rename(columns=str.lower, inplace=True)` is much cleaner and to the point.