# How to convert these functions to act on the entire dataframe and speed up my python code

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, pyalgotrade

In an attempt to backtest the much-discussed trading approach known as the Smart Money Concept, I made a Python class with a few functions.

Now, the mistake I made was to make each function operate on the last candle/row and return results only for that row/candle. This has turned out to be a mistake because it will take a very long time to loop over the `dataframe` and feed each row to these functions if I was to backtest with six months' worth of data.

I require assistance with:

Converting the public functions/methods to act on the entire `dataframe` via `vectorization` and return the entire `dataframe`.

`is_uptrend()`, `has_bull_choch()`

---

Below is the source code:

```py
from scipy.ndimage import  maximum_filter1d, minimum_filter1d
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from scipy import stats

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class SmartMoney:
    
    def get_supports_and_resistances(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        df['is_support'] = 0
        df['is_resistance'] = 0
        df = self._get_resistances(df=df)
        df = self._get_supports(df=df)

        return df


    # Get support zones
    def _get_supports(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        if len(df) < 1:
            return df

        smoothed_low = minimum_filter1d(df.low, self.filter_size) if self.filter_size > 0 else df.low
        minimas, _ = find_peaks(x=-smoothed_low, prominence=self.look_back(df=df))

        if len(minimas) > 0:
            df.loc[minimas, 'is_support'] = 1        
        return df

    # Get resistances zones
    def _get_resistances(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        if len(df) < 1:
            return df

        smoothed_high = maximum_filter1d(df.high, self.filter_size) if self.filter_size > 0 else df.high
        maximas, _ = find_peaks(smoothed_high, prominence=self.look_back(df=df))
        if len(maximas) > 0:
            df.loc[maximas, 'is_resistance'] = 1
        return df

    def look_back(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> int:
        return round(np.mean(df['high'] - df['low']))        

    def is_uptrend(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> bool:
        if self._meets_requirement(df=df) == False:
            return False
        return (
                    df.loc[df['is_resistance'] == 1, 'high'].iloc[-1] > df.loc[df['is_resistance'] == 1, 'high'].iloc[-2] and 
                    df.loc[df['is_support'] == 1, 'low'].iloc[-1] > df.loc[df['is_support'] == 1, 'low'].iloc[-2]  
                )

    def is_downtrend(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> bool:
        if self._meets_requirement(df=df) == False:
            return False
        return (
                    df.loc[df['is_resistance'] == 1, 'high'].iloc[-1] < df.loc[df['is_resistance'] == 1, 'high'].iloc[-2] and 
                    df.loc[df['is_support'] == 1, 'low'].iloc[-1] < df.loc[df['is_support'] == 1, 'low'].iloc[-2]  
                )

    def _meets_requirement(self, df: pd.DataFrame, minimum_required: int = 2) -> bool:
        return len(df.loc[df['is_resistance'] == 1]) >= minimum_required and len(df.loc[df['is_support'] == 1]) >= minimum_required
        
    # Check if there's Change of Character (as per Smart Money Concept)
    def has_bull_choch(self, df: pd.DataFrame, in_pullback_phase = False, with_first_impulse = False) -> bool:
        if df[df['is_resistance'] == 1].empty:
            return False
        
        left, right = self._get_left_and_right(df = df, divide_by_high=False)

        if len(left[left['is_resistance'] == 1]) < 1 or right.shape[0] < 1:
            return False

        # if we only want CHoCH that broke on first impulse move
        if with_first_impulse:
            if left.loc[left['is_resistance'] == 1, 'high'].iloc[-1] > right.loc[right['is_resistance'] == 1, 'high'].iloc[0] :
                return False

        # if we want CHoCH in pullback phase
        if in_pullback_phase:
            if right.iloc[right[right['is_resistance'] == 1].index[-1], right.columns.get_loc('high')] < right['high'].iloc[-1]:
                return False
        
        tmp = right[right['high'] > left.loc[left['is_resistance'] == 1, 'high'].iloc[-1]]
        if tmp.shape[0] > 0 :
            return True
        return False
    
    def _get_left_and_right(self, df: pd.DataFrame, divide_by_high = True) -> tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]:
       
       # Get the lowest/highest support df
        off_set = df['low'].idxmin() if divide_by_high == False else df['high'].idxmax()

        # Get list of df before lowest support
        left    =   df[:off_set]

        # take only resistance and leave out support
        # left    =   left[left['is_resistance'] == 1]
        left.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) 


        # Get list aft the df after loweset support
        right   =   df[off_set:]

        # take only resistance and leave out support
        # right   =   right[right['is_resistance'] == 1]
        right.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        return pd.DataFrame(left), pd.DataFrame(right)
```

Test Data:

```py
import yfinance as yfd
ticker_symbol = "BTC-USD"

start_date = "2023-06-01"
end_date = "2023-12-31"

bitcoin_data = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start=start_date, end=end_date)

# Reset the index to make the date a regular column
df = bitcoin_data.reset_index()

df.rename(columns={'Date': 'time', 'Open': 'open', 'High': 'high', 'Low': 'low', 'Close': 'close', 'adj close': 'adj close', 'Volume': 'volume'}, inplace=True)
```

## This is how i would like the code to work

```py
from smart_money import SmartMoney
sm = SmartMoney()

# Get minimas and maximas (support and resistance)
df = sm.get_supports_and_resistances(df=df)
df = sm.is_uptrend(df=df)
df = sm.has_bull_choch(df=df)
```

Remember the objective is to have these function return a `Dataframe` with new column (name of column should be be the function name), column value can be a 1 or 0.

| time | open | high | low | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324 | 2023-11-28 | 37242.70 | 38377.00 | 36868.41 | 37818.87 |
| 325 | 2023-11-29 | 37818.88 | 38450.00 | 37570.00 | 37854.64 |
| 326 | 2023-11-30 | 37854.65 | 38145.85 | 37500.00 | 37723.96 |
| 327 | 2023-12-01 | 37723.97 | 38999.00 | 37615.86 | 38682.52 |
| 328 | 2023-12-02 | 38682.51 | 38821.59 | 38641.61 | 38774.95 |

Comment: could you provide an example input?

Comment: I have added sample code for getting Test Data.

Comment: Which function you want to apply to whole dataframe? All you provide here are return a boolean while the `get_left_and_right` just divide the data into two parts.

Comment: `is_uptrend` and `has_bull_choch` those two functions should add additional column (can use function name) to the dataframe and return the Dataframe.

Comment: got it I'll try to solve your problem as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is what I eventually accomplished after much effort.**

I will try to work on other functions as well.

---

*Also compared execution time (From `2020-01-01` to `2023-12-31`):*

Explicit Loop:

`CPU times: user 2.15 s, sys: 7.77 ms, total: 2.16 s Wall time: 2.17 s`

Vectorized Code:

`CPU times: user 3.79 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 3.79 ms Wall time: 3.58 ms`

I will also check how execution time is affected when running on lower timeframe like `1h`, `30m` and `15m`

```py
def is_uptrend(self, data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:

    resistance_condition = (data['is_resistance'] == 1)
    cum_resistance = resistance_condition.cumsum()
    grouped_resistances = np.split(cum_resistance, np.where(np.diff(cum_resistance) != 0)[0] + 1)
    
    support_condition = (data['is_support'] == 1)
    cum_support = support_condition.cumsum()
    grouped_supports = np.split(cum_support, np.where(np.diff(cum_support) != 0)[0] + 1)

    
    high_condition = (
        data['High'].shift(len(grouped_resistances[-1])) > data['High'].shift(len(grouped_resistances[-2]))
    )

    low_condition = (
        data['Low'].shift(len(grouped_supports[-1])) > data['Low'].shift(len(grouped_supports[-2]))
    )

    data['is_uptrend'] = (high_condition & low_condition).astype(int)

    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

#### description

- You need to know the type of `df['is_support']` is a list. python can not auto set all value to each element/row of `df['is_support']`
- So you need generator whole list and then assign whole list to `df['is_support']`, not pass `df` everywhere.
- I'll provide an example code to you, not just correct whole class for you, please try to learn how to use a `list`.
- hint:When you need to apply a function to a list or specifically `df['{a field name}']`, you may need `map`;When you need create a list or specifically `df['is_support']`, you may need `list comprehension`.

#### example code:

- main.py

```
import yfinance as yf
from smart_money import SmartMoney
ticker_symbol = "BTC-USD"
start_date = "2023-01-01"
end_date = "2023-12-31"
bitcoin_data = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start=start_date, end=end_date)
bitcoin_data = bitcoin_data.reset_index()
df = bitcoin_data[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]
df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)
df.insert(0,"time",range(1, len(df) + 1))
sm = SmartMoney()
df = sm.get_supports_and_resistances(df=df)
print(df)
print(df['is_support'])
```

- smart_money.py

```
class SmartMoney:
    def _fake_get_supports(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        return [1 for _ in range(len(df))]

    def _fake_get_resistances(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        return [0 for _ in range(len(df))]

    def get_supports_and_resistances(self, df: pd.DataFrame, strict: bool = False) -> pd.DataFrame:
        df['is_support'] = self._fake_get_supports(df=df)
        df['is_resistance'] = self._fake_get_resistances(df=df)
        return df
```

- result:

```
     time          open          high           low         close       volume  is_support  is_resistance
0       1  16547.914062  16630.439453  16521.234375  16625.080078   9244361700           1              0
1       2  16625.509766  16759.343750  16572.228516  16688.470703  12097775227           1              0
2       3  16688.847656  16760.447266  16622.371094  16679.857422  13903079207           1              0
......
```

- useful link:

1. [Add column to the end of Pandas DataFrame containing average of previous data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698861/add-column-to-the-end-of-pandas-dataframe-containing-average-of-previous-data)
2. [How can I make pandas dataframe column headers all lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726029/how-can-i-make-pandas-dataframe-column-headers-all-lowercase)
3. [Understanding the map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function)
4. [Python list function or list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861577/python-list-function-or-list-comprehension)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but i was avoiding the explicit `loops` and `maps` to do that because it is taking forever when i loop through 3 month worth of data or more.

I tried using `np.apply_along_axis(self.is_uptrend, axis=1, arr=dataframe, df=dataframe)` and it took a lot of time.

Which is why i want each function (`is_uptrend()`, `has_bull_choch()`) to use vectorization and return `Dataframe` without using explicite loops and maps.

like on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxWginnBklU

Comment: @chawila ok now I know the real problem you want to solve, I'll try to solve it tomorrow. Sry I'm busy today.